# Field Extensions Question

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and $E$ be an extension of $F$. Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of $F$ with $b \neq 0$, and let $t$ be an element of $E$ that is not in $F$. Show that $F(a + bt) = F(t)$.

**Proof**

Let $a,b \in F$ with $b \neq 0$ and let $t \in E$ that is not in $F$. Clearly, then since $E$ is an extension of $F$. $F(a+bt)\subseteq F(t)$. Now, let us prove that $F(t) \subseteq F(a+bt)$.

This is what I have so far. I dont know how to prove that $F(t) \subseteq F(a+bt)$.

Answer (score 2):

If we set $u=a+bt$ then $t=b^{-1}u-b^{-1}a$, so for the same reason
that $F(at+b)\subseteq F(t)$
then $F(t)=F(b^{-1}u-b^{-1}a)\subseteq F(u)=F(a+bt)$.